# How do I partially update an array inside and object in MongoDB so the new value is added to the array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, routes, mongoose-populate

Given the following schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var favoriteSchema = new Schema({
dishes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Dish'
}],
postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
}, {
 timestamps: true
});

var Favorites = mongoose.model('Favorite', favoriteSchema);
module.exports = Favorites;
```

and the following router

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Favorites = require('../models/favorites');
var Verify = require('./verify');

var favoritesRouter = express.Router();

favoritesRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
favoritesRouter.route('/')
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req,res,next){
    req.body.postedBy = req.decoded._doc._id;
    console.log('nana ' + req.body.postedBy);
    Favorites.create(req.body,function(err,fav){
        if(err) throw err;

        fav.dishes.push(req.body);
        fav.save(function(err,fa){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(fa);
        })
    });
});
module.exports = favoritesRouter;
```

Every time i do the post requires from postman, I`m attaching the dish ID to the body of the request.

```
 {
   "_id": "577a996155d73cf02b0d516f"
 }
```

I could not come up with a solution to insert this ID into the array, instead of re-creating the whole object with only 1 id inside the array. Am i making something wrong, or something else has to be done in order to do the logic i want?

Comment: You are using `req.body` like it is both a `favorite` and a `dish`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to query the database to find the previously saved object, append to the array, mark as modified, then save. It will look something like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Favorites = require('../models/favorites');
var Verify = require('./verify');

var favoritesRouter = express.Router();

favoritesRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
favoritesRouter.route('/')
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req,res,next){
    req.body.postedBy = req.decoded._doc._id;
    console.log('nana ' + req.body.postedBy);
    Favorites.findById(someID, function(err, fav){
        if(err) throw err;

        fav.dishes.push(req.body);
        fav.markModified('dishes')
        fav.save(function(err,fa){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(fa);
        })
    });
});
```

You'll need to figure out how you're getting the ID in there. You could use a dynamic endpoint:

```
favoritesRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
favoritesRouter.route('/:id')
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req,res,next){
    var someID = req.params.id
})
```

Or you could do a search for who posted it (`.find({postedBy: req.decoded._doc._id},...` instead of `.findById(someID,...`), or something else

Comment: Just curious, what does markModiefied do? I'm never doing that and it works fine :D

Comment: Hmmm. It appears I'm a bit overzealous with markModified. You have to use it with mongoose when you're directly editing an array element (e.g. `fav.dishes[3] = 'PulledPork'`), it appears it may not actually be necessary when pushing to the end of the array. For more info, see here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html